# Understanding if statements in EWD931

Tags: logic, continuity

EWD931 is: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd09xx/EWD931.PDF, which proposes an interesting structure with continuous truth values. Note therefore that the symbols I use in this question use his notation not standard notation.

He remarks that $x \land y \equiv x$ (or $x \lor y \equiv y$) are equivalent to $x \implies y$. Why is this true? I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that at the end of the second page he defined $x\Rightarrow y$ to be a shorthand for either expressions you mentioned ($x\vee y\equiv y, x\wedge y\equiv x$), and presumably you already know those two are equivalent.

If you really wonder why this definition is made, try the degenerate case of $x,y=0,1$. In fact the top of the third page already lists quite a few of interesting properties it has.